# Why cant i take multiple dictionary values and put them into the same variable

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def ULIfrom(in1):
    out1 = 0
    out2 = ""
    out3 = ""
    dict2 = {' ':int(0),'a':int(1),'b':int(2),'c':int(3),'d':int(4),'e':int(5),'f':int(6),'g':int(7),'h':int(8),
             'i':int(9),'j':int(10),'k':int(11),'l':int(12),'m':int(13),'n':int(14),'o':int(15),'p':int(16),'q':int(17),
             'r':int(18),'s':int(19),'t':int(20),'u':int(21),'v':int(22),'w':int(23),'x':int(24),'y':int(25),'z':int(26)
             }
    for x in in1:
        if x == ".":
            out2 = dict2.get(out1)
            out3 += out2
        else:
            if x == "U":
                out1 += 10
            elif x == "L":
                out1 += 5
            elif x == "I":
                out1 += 1
    return(out2)

print (ULIfrom(input("enter your encoded phrase:")))
```

---

I am fairly new to coding so i don't know whats going on when I try to store multiple dictionary values in the out3 variable and it says that you cant combine NoneTypes and strings because the dictionary values that come out should be strings.

Comment: What are you entering as `"enter your encoded phrase:"`?

Comment: `out2 = dict2.get(out1)` is trying to get the value of the key out1 = 0 which doesn't exist in your dict2, it returns None.

Comment: The function as it is makes no sense. It always returns `out2`. `out2` is only set if `x` is `'.'` and for that value we have no entry in the dictionary. Why do we need `out2` and `out3`? Could you explain what your function should do?

Comment: BTW, you don't have to write `int(1)`. Just `1` is enough, because `1` is already an integer. And drop the parentheses after `return`. `return` is not a function, but a statement.

Comment: an exaple of the og code would be LIII.L.UII.UII.UL./.UUIII.UL.ULIII.IIII. meaning HELLO WORLD.

Answer (score 0):

You generated a dictionary that maps from a single character string key to an integer values, but the rest of your code seems to require the opposite mapping - translating from an integer to a character.

Additionally, when you concatenate `out2` to `out3` you do not test to see if it is a string returned from the dictionary lookup (if the key is found), or a `None` value. You should either skip concatenation if `out2 == None`, or give the call to `get` a default string value (to return if key not in the dictionary):

```
        out2 = dict2.get(out1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's somehow unclear what the result of your function should be. I guess you want to traverse all characters in `in1` and add the values from the dictionary as the total. You might want to use more meaningful names for the variables in the future, so you and other readers can figure out what they should contain.

There's no need to write down every value of the mapping dictionary. Write a dictionary comprehension and let Python do that for you. The cases for the letters `'U'`, `'L'` and `'I'` can be added to the dictionary, so you don't have to deal with them later in the code.

Then loop over the string, find the entry from the dictionary (with default value `0`)  and add those values to get the total.

```
import string

def ULIfrom(data):
    mapping = {char: ord(char) - ord('a') + 1 for char in string.ascii_lowercase}
    mapping['U'] = 10
    mapping['L'] = 5
    mapping['I'] = 1

    total = 0
    for character in data:
        total += mapping.get(character, 0)

    return total


print(ULIfrom(input("enter your encoded phrase:")))
```

You can shorten this code even more if you replace

```
    total = 0
    for character in data:
        total += mapping.get(character, 0)

    return total
```

with

```
    return sum(mapping.get(character, 0) for character in data)
```

---

After clarification of the question I adjusted the code to:

```
def get_text_from_ULI(uli):
    MAP_CODE = {'U': 10, 'L': 5, 'I': 1}
    MAP_NUMBER_TO_CHAR = {ord(char) - ord('a') + 1: char for char in string.ascii_lowercase}

    text = ''
    words = uli.split('/')
    for word in words:
        codes = word.split('.')
        for code in codes:
            number = sum(MAP_CODE.get(c, 0) for c in code)
            character = MAP_NUMBER_TO_CHAR.get(number, '')
            text += character
        text += ' '
    return text

print(get_text_from_ULI('LIII.L.UII.UII.UL./.UUIII.UL.ULIII.IIII.'))
```

The result is `hello word`.

---

And now for the really evil stuff. I assumed valid input to make the code a little bit shorter. Here is a one-liner:

```
def get_text_from_ULI(uli):
    return ' '.join(''.join({ord(char)-ord('a')+1:char for char in string.ascii_lowercase}[sum({'U':10,'L':5,'I':1}[c]for c in code)]for code in word.split('.') if code)for word in uli.split('/'))
```

**Kids, don't do that at home!**

Comment: That's really good code but i need to find the value for each set of code inside two full stops and change that into a letter which i can then put into a variable with the rest of the letters to fully translate the word

Answer (score 0):

---

Thanks to everyone for helping, i finally finished the code.

```
def ULIto(in1):
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,
         'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,
         'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26
         }
out1 = ""
out2 = ""
for x in in1:
    if x == " ":
        out2 = (out2 + "/")
    else:
        out1 = 0
        out1 =(dict1.get(x))
        if out1 >= 10:
            while out1 >= 10:
                out1 = out1-10
                out2 = (out2 + "U")
        if out1 >= 5:
            while out1 >= 5:
                out1 = out1-5
                out2 = (out2 + "L")
        if out1 >= 1:
            while out1 >= 1:
                out1 = out1-1
                out2 = (out2 + "I")
        out2 = out2+"."
out2 = out2+" "

return out2
```

print(ULIto(input("Enter your (lowercase letters only)phrase:")))

---

this is a func to change words into code

```
def ULIfrom(in1):
out1 = 0
out2 = ""
dict2 = {0 : " ",1 : "a",2 : "b",3 : "c",4 : "d",5 : "e",6 : "f",
         7 : "g",8 : "h",9 : "i",10 : "j",11 : "k",12 : "l",13 : "m",
         14 : "n",15 : "o",16 : "p",17 : "q",18 : "r",19 : "s",20 : "t",
         21 : "u",22 : "v",23 : "w",24 : "x",25 : "y",26 : "z"
         }
for x in in1:
    if x == "/":
        out2 += " "
    if x == ".":
        out2 += dict2.get(out1, '')
        out1 = 0
    else:
        if x == "U":
            out1 += 10
        elif x == "L":
            out1 += 5
        elif x == "I":
            out1 += 1
return out2
```

print (ULIfrom(input("enter your encoded phrase:")))

---

this func is to change code back to words.

Comment: After this explanation I adjusted my answer. If you continue to learn Python you'll understand it later. ;)